# How does WebcamToy get weird effects on top of getUserMedia() webcam video?

Tags: javascript, webgl, getusermedia

I know how to access the webcam using getUserMedia() in Javascript. However, I am impressed by all the effects that have been added in webcamtoy.com - especially effects such as "Top mirror", "Tunnel", "Shuffle" and so on. It seems like these are not plain CSS filters [1]. It is impressive to see them working "live" in the browser.

I am wondering if anyone here knows what the technique used is? .. and if there are any websites which explain how this can be done?

[1] https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. The idea is to setup a WebGL canvas and use the webcam as the source for the texture. Then weird effects can be added by modifying the fragment shader.

I am testing the technique here: https://www.html5fun.com/webgl/webglswirl2.php

Comment: Did you ever make more of these?

Comment: Well, not so much. Just this one: https://www.html5fun.com/webgl/webcamcube.php
But if you know GL shader coding, you should be able to modify the webglswirl2.php code above to do anything really.

Comment: @rubund how did you put the mediastream to canvas ? so far i've had to use a <video> element with my mediastream, and a canvas for the captured snapshots i take, i'd love to cut out the <video> element, and simply use a canvas that switches between snapshots and stream input, also being able to use custom filters is a plus